# Custom view hides UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I click on a `UITableViewCell` a custom view shows up. But sometimes this view hides the selected `UITableViewCell`.

I can solve this problem by using:

```
[self.tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                                  animated:YES];
```

But this seems only to work if there are more cells than the tableview can display on the screen.

Can I somehow force the tableview to scroll anyway? Or do I need to go a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution is simply scrolling up the table view by the same height of the custom view and scroll down by setting table view's `contentOffset`.